# Why does ethminer only show 3GB on my Sapphire R7 370 4GB?

Tags: mining, bug, ethminer, genoil

Ethminer found my Sapphire R7 370 Nitro 4GB but only shows 3221225472 bytes of memory.

My r7 had 4GB of memory.

I would like to konw why my Sapphire R7 370 4GB only use 3GB of gpu memory.

I am using the last version of ethmine (Ethminer 0.9.41-genoil-1.0.4b3) on operating system is Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Has nobody an idea? I am grateful for every tip

Comment: that's indeed very strange. did you try to use differtent tools to diagnose the gpu memory?

Comment: Yes i uesd gpu-z and eversthome and they show 4GB gpu memory.

Comment: Ok then it might be a bug in genoil's code. Or it's a 32/64 bit issue?

Comment: what can i do? Is the ethminer open source ?

Comment: Genoil's isnt, but you can download the open source version [here](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases/).

Comment: I can confirm that I have a same Issue and it doesn't have anything to do with genoil. The problem exist in Ethminer 0.9.41 also.

Comment: Hey, i found solution (cannot put it as answer) 
setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 1
on ubuntu
export GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR =1

Answer (score 1):

My fork is open source. I didn't write the code that counts RAM on OpenCL devices though, but I have never seen it report the wrong size on any card I have used. Perhaps it is an OpenCL driver issue.

Anyway it's not a big deal for ETH mining, 3GB is enough.

edit: create a bat file with these and insert your ethminer launch command  in the last line. that should fix it.

```
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1 
setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0 
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
ethminer -G ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
How much does the 1GB more on speed ?
Can you fix this? Or is that too complicated ?
I use 4 x R7 370 Nitro .

Comment: Exactly 0H/s. In other words, nothing. That said, it is strange why it is listed as 3GB. Can you paste your full launch bat file?

Comment: see edited Answer

Comment: I have the orders already in my file , but that does not help .
Thank you for your help